# Linked ARM templates result in Invalid Template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Let's start with what I'm trying to accomplish.

What I'd like to do is create an ARM template where I'm retrieving secrets from the Azure Key Vault, without specifying too much details on the specific Key Vault. Sounds easy enough and probably something which is implemented in every production system.

Doing a quick search I discovered [the syntax for such a thing is the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-dynamic-id).

```
"parameters": {
  "adminPassword": {
    "reference": {
      "keyVault": {
        "id": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId,  parameters('vaultResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
      },
      "secretName": "[parameters('secretName')]"
    }
  },
```

From what I gather you need to add this in an external template as the used methods can't be used in the 'main' method.

So I started creating a 'main' ARM template and a new template called `appservice.json` which contains all of the stuff necessary for my App Service, including the `appSettings` block which need the secrets from Key Vault.

In my main template I've done the following, [as described in the documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates.md#using-variables-to-link-templates).

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "linkedTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'appservice.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
```

However, when deploying I'm confronted with the following error.

```
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/ba49bae7-2b37-4504-914b-441763a2bcd3/resourceGroups/cfpexchange-jan-test/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/linkedTemplate' at line '1' and column '1526'. 'The language expression property 'templateLink' doesn't exist, available properties are 'name, properties'.'"
  }
```

I also tried the following because I noticed IntelliSense in Visual Studio told me `properties` doesn't exits and I should use `templateLink` directly.

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "linkedTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[uri(deployment().templateLink.uri, 'appservice.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
```

This of course isn't right either.

```
   "error": {
    "code": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/ba49bae7-2b37-4504-914b-441763a2bcd3/resourceGroups/cfpexchange-jan-test/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/linkedTemplate' at line '1' and column '1526'. 'The language expression property 'templateLink' doesn't exist, available properties are 'name, properties'.'"
  }
```

And when using it as a variable, like in the documentation

```
"variables": {
    "sharedTemplateUrl": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'shared-resources.json')]"
  },
...
"properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('sharedTemplateUrl')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
```

I'm also getting an error.

> 2018-07-04T19:14:34.4204720Z ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'sharedTemplateUrl' is not valid: The language expression property 'templateLink' doesn't exist, available properties are 'template, parameters, mode, debugSetting, provisioningState'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.

At this time I'm a bit lost. From what I understand from the documentation it appears I'm doing everything correct. Apparently I'm not. Any ideas on how to continue with this?

For completeness, the two actual files which I'm using at this time:

- The main ARM template: https://github.com/Jandev/CfpExchange/blob/b998bb0c49cf369b2f7584e20556aefb5224ace0/Deployment/CFPExchange.json
- The linked template: https://github.com/Jandev/CfpExchange/blob/522f48aa19d19730e5474ce11ead57a48d330389/Deployment/appservice.json

There have been multiple iterations on it in order to try and fix it, but as mentioned noting appeared to be working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [this](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/ml-vm-ml-dd-kv.json#L84) is how you are supposed to use KV in a nested template. Example with Admin password:

```
"adminPassword": {
    "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
            "id": "kv_resource_id"
        },
        "secretName": "[concat('secret', copyindex(1))]"
    }
},
```

This section supposed to be in the nested template parameters WHEN you invoke it (just look at the example link).

Your error seems to be in the variable. So the templateLink property is only available when you deploy your main template from the url, if you use local file to deploy main template it wont work.

[image]

Compare this to remote template execution:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxx -TemplateUri 'https://paste.ee/d/XI1Rc/0'
```

As this is a remote url, it should show you the same output, but this time with a `templateLink` property.

```
Name             Type                       Value
===============  =========================  ==========
test             Object                     {

"name": "theDeploymentName",
"properties": {
  "templateLink": {
    "uri": "theRemoteTemplateUri"
  },
  "template": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
      "test": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": "[deployment()]"
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {},
  "mode": "Incremental",
  "provisioningState": "Accepted"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting the template to work with the KV id specified like you mentioned (`"id": "/subscriptions/c6af39f7-0fce-432b-98cd-c34fe14e6a66/resourceGroups/testo/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/vaulty"`) will indeed solve the issue. But the linked documentation and sample (https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/blob/master/azure-resource-manager/keyvaultparameter/sqlserver-dynamic-id.json) show these hardcoded values can (or should) also be able substituted with a dynamic function. I'll try the `templateLink` suggestion sometime later today!

Comment: yeah, you can use function to determine KV resource id, its just an example. I'm using `resourceId()` in my templates mostly. My point about KV reference was: you are using it in a wrong place, it can ONLY be used in the parameters section of a template

Comment: `So the templateLink property is only available when you deploy your main template from the url, if you use local file to deploy main template it wont work.` This might be a good pointer to the right direction! I'm using VSTS do handle the deployments. My guess the buildserver is downloading all artifacts locally and deploying it from local files and not from a remote file. Will dig into this, thanks!